# String built with carriage returns such as \n\r still comes as one line

Tags: c#, sql

In my code I iterate through an array of strings and concatenate them into one long string that I pass into a stored procedure. That, in turn, writes into a database table. I want the string to look like this in the database table:

```
string1,
string2,
string3,
.
.
.
stringN.
```

But it appears in the database in the following format:

```
string1, string2, string3, ... stringN.
```

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg.Count; i++) 
   messages += msg[i] + ",\n\r";
```

and after the string is constructed I write it to database:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg", msg);
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You want `\r\n`, not `\n\r`. Also I assume you are viewing in straight up `notepad` because every other text editor I've ever used will newline on `\n` alone. I tend to only use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you are looking in the database using something like _Sql Server Management Studio_, you`ll see all in one line, but when you retrieve the data it would be ok,with all the carriage returns

Comment: Thanks Pikoh, that was the right answer. After I linked the table to Access and viewed it from there , all the messages appeared in one column